# issue facing with find command in linux

Tags: shell

I am facing one problem using `find` command. I have below directory structure. In which a,b,c directories contain some files but i want to scan only b directory when i am using below command it scans c directory as well which is not required.

```
/a/b/c/

find /a/b/ f -type -mtime +90
```

Is there any solution to resolve this problem?

Please assist.

i want to write a find command which scans a directory for files but does not scan files of its subdirectories.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
find /a/b/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +90
```

Comment: Explaining the solution is usually beneficial. I presume here it's the maxdepth parameter that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-maxdepth 1` to look in the `b` directory only.

```
find /a/b/ -type f mtime +90 -maxdepth 1
```

From `man find`:

> -maxdepth levels
>
> Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below
>           the  command  line arguments.  '-maxdepth 0' means only apply the tests and
>           actions to the command line arguments.